# In Game Programming (And OOP Generally), When do we Decide to Use the Command vs the State Design Pattern?

Tags: oop, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I'm reading in Game Programming Patterns that Commands should be used to give directions for actors, and States are used to indicate a single state the actor would be in (standing, jumping, moving, etc).

I'm currently working on a problem in my codebase right now that I can't seem to wrap my head around in a good way. I currently have 3 "Interaction States" that my characters can be in - Passive, Melee Combat, or Ranged Combat.

And there are several what I *think* of as Commands currently that a character can be in - Moving, Talking, Attacking, etc. But a character can't be attacking in a passive state, or talking in a combat state - my question is do these commands make more sense as Commands or as States, and I can build a concurrent/hierarchical state machine?

Also, should we think of Commands as the actions that move characters from state to state (e.g. if I right click an enemy I pass the "attack" Command into the State constructor to move from "move" state to "attack" state)? I guess I'm just having a hard time conceptualizing what to do here and how states and commands interact.

Example State, would be attached to a character object:

```
public class MeleeState : InteractionState
{
    public override void HandleInput(Character character, InteractionCommands command)
    {
        base.HandleInput(character, command);

        if (command == InteractionCommands.CHANGETOPASSIVE)
        {

        }
        else if (command == InteractionCommands.CHANGETORANGED)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Example Command:

```
public class Attack : Command
{

    Attack(Character aggressor, Enemy victim)
    {

    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();
    }

    public override void Undo()
    {
        base.Undo();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***I think***, all of them can be seen as states. That is passive, walking, jumping, MeleeCombat**ING**, RangedCombat**ING** can be considered as states.
We pass a command to walk , so the character's state changes to waking state from passive states.
And in the cases you pointed out , we should not provide any implementation for attacking when the character is in a passive state, or no talking implementation when in a combat state

At an give point in time the character is in some state, until a command(RangedCombatCommand) is given. Upon receiving the command the character will be in commbat state and will be performing RangedCombat